# jquery .change function on ie

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I have a problem binding to the `change` event in Internet Explorer.

I have the following code:

```
$("#tbFechaValides").attr("disabled", "disabled");

$("#tbCodigo").change(function() {
                window.alert("ddd");
                if ($(this).val() != " ") {

                    $("#tbFechaValides").removeAttr('disabled');

                } else {
                    $("#tbFechaValides").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            });
```

It works in Firefox but when I test it in IE nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not triggering events, you're binding an event handler...

Comment: Your code works isolated: http://jsfiddle.net/NxnXZ/. So perhaps you have an error further up that's making this code not run in IE. I tested in IE 7 and 8.

Comment: sorry my mistake, but still can't found why it doesn´t work on ie, but work on other explorer

Comment: Can you post a link to the page in question? I have a feeling that there is at least one other error on the page.

Comment: i'm developing rigth know, i doesn't have anything deployed :(

Comment: I don't think that is the reason why it's not working in ie, but you should change this-> `if ($(this).val() != " ")` as this-> `if ($(this).val() != "")`, they are different.

Comment: What kind of element is tbCodigo?

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML.  We need to know what type of object `#tbCodigo` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a sweep for `console.log` which might be lurking around in your other scripts.  IE will choke on this by default.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your script inside the document ready

```
$(function(){

   $("#tbFechaValides").attr("disabled", "disabled");

   $("#tbCodigo").change(function() {
                window.alert("ddd");
                if ($(this).val() != "") {

                    $("#tbFechaValides").removeAttr('disabled');

                } else {
                    $("#tbFechaValides").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
    });    

});
```

I dont know how your HTML looks like. But i create a sample with a text box and a HTML Select and it worked fine for me in all browsers. The only change i made is changing " " to ""

jsFiddle sample  http://jsfiddle.net/ptCHx/1/

Comment: alredy inside  $(document).ready(function() ... i have lots of scripts there, but this specifically doesn't work on ie, but works on firefox or chrome

Comment: @AlejandroHinestrosa: I guess some other Script error then. Are you seeing some script errors in firebug console

Comment: To debug in IE, you can try Firebug Lite which is a bookmarklet (since IE's debugging tools leave a lot to be desired): http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Comment: yes, 'cause i test everything on firefox, and firebug doesn't show anything wrong

Comment: @AlejandroHinestrosa: Try clearning IE browser cache and see again

Comment: @shyju, it works perfect if i activate the textbox from a dropdown list, my problem is in this case especifically, in fact i have another aplication with a similar structure and it works well on IE and firefox